# Java - Return different classes from method and use specific functions of the classes

Tags: java, class

I have 2 classes.For example ; Rectangle and Circle

```
public class Rectangle {
    private int width;
    private int height;
    public Rectangle(int width,int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    public int getArea() {
        return width * height;
    }
}
public class Circle {
    private int radius;
    public Circle(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    public int getArea() {
        return radius * radius * 3;
    }
}
```

and I have this method out of classes;

```
public void PrintArea(Object object) {
    if(object instanceof Circle)
        System.out.print(((Circle)object).getArea());
    else if(object instanceof Rectangle)
        System.out.print(((Rectangle)object).getArea());
}
```

but I want to do it on one line without class cast, For example:

```
public void PrintArea(Object object) {
    System.out.print(object.getArea());
}
```

is it possible? Thank you... (Circle and Rectangle are only examples.I have different and detailed classes in big project.And I cannot change this class structure)

Comment: sure. Have them implement an interface 'Shape' which defines an int getArea() method, and have PrintArea (which should be named printArea) accept an instance of Shape as parameter, not an Object

Comment: Circle and Rectangle are only examples.I have different and detailed classes in big project.And I cannot change this class structure.

Comment: then no, you can't. at least not without casting it to the right type somehow. After all, you pass a type Object. Object doesn't contain a getArea() method

Comment: if there is alternative method please tell me (one line is not essential)

Comment: You may be able to use some ways to get the class from the object, and then to cast it to that class, but it remains a fact you can pass any Object to that method, meaning it will crash if you pass a type that doesn't have that method.

Comment: No problem.I pass only 2 classes to that method

Comment: you do .. now. but trust me, sooner or later, someone will drop by and pass another type.
But seriously, if you plan only to pass those two and never any other, why trying to look for a generic solution? Yes, it's better and cleaner, but a bit redundant if you already know the types, especially if the obvious ways are not possible

Comment: because I repeat this cast too much (50+)

Comment: I think I've found a solution to your issue, will add an answer so you can check.

Comment: Ok.I am waiting.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Polymorphism to invoke the method of the correct instance at runtime. To do this you can make a interface `Shape` which has the `printArea()` method. This method would be implemented by the concrete classes `Rectangle` and `Circle` which would define their specific behaviour:

```
interface Shape {
   void printArea();
}

class Rectangle implements Shape {
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getArea() {
        return width * height;
    }

    public void printArea() {
        System.out.println(this.getArea());
    }
}

class Circle implements Shape {
    private int radius;

    public Circle(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public int getArea() {
        return radius * radius * 3;
    }

    public void printArea() {
        System.out.println(this.getArea());
    }
}
```

Then there would a dispatcher class like `Printer` which takes a shape object and calls the `printArea()` method on it:

```
class Printer {
    public void printArea(Shape shape) {
            shape.printArea();
    }
}
```

Then you could do something like this to use the dynamic method dispatch concept in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 20);
        rectangle.printArea();
        Shape circle = new Circle(20);
        circle.printArea();
        Printer printer = new Printer();
        printer.printArea(circle);
        printer.printArea(rectangle);
}
```

**EDIT**

---

If you can't add new methods in the classes then you can go for `default` methods in the `Shape` interface introduced from Java 8:

```
interface Shape {
    int getArea();
    default void printArea(){
        System.out.println(this.getArea());
    }
}
```

Now lets say if you need a `Square` implementation, and have the `getArea` defined then you no longer have to define a `printArea()` method in the class `Square`:

```
class Square implements Shape{
    private int side;

    public Square(int side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

    public int getArea() {
        return side * side;
    }
}
```

This way you don't break the existing implementations when you implement the new `Shape` interface in existing classes.

Comment: Circle and Rectangle are only examples.I have different and detailed classes in big project.And I cannot change this class structure.

Comment: I cannot use interface because of my structure.But thank you for answers.I will accept your answer,this is my mistake.

Comment: @FullstackGuy in order to use the default methods, he still needs to change his classes to implement the interface.

Comment: @Stultuske yes, that is the only minimal required change, it would also help in having a well defined behaviour if the type is known beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write an interface with getArea () method. And you should make Rectangle and Circle implement the interface.

```java
public interface Shape {
    int getArea();
}

public class Rectangle implements Shape {
    private int width;
    private int height;
    public Rectangle(int width,int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    @Override
    public int getArea() {
            return width * height;
    }
}
public class Circle implements Shape {
    private int radius;
    public Circle(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    @Override
    public int getArea() {
        return radius * radius * 3;
    }
}
```

and..

```java
public void PrintArea(Object object) {
    if(object instanceof Shape)
        System.out.print((Shape)object.getArea());
}

//or..

public void PrintArea(Shape object) {
    object.getArea();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflections inside the printArea method but it is not recommended way of doing it. Use either interface or extend from an abstract base class

One way of doing it is below.

```
public void PrintArea(Object object) throws Exception {
        Method method = object.getClass().getMethod("getArea");
        System.out.println(method.invoke(object));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have your two classes, Rectangle and Circle.

These two classes, you can't alter, so you can't make them implement an interface.

You can, however, locally extend them, and have those subclasses implement an interface.

```
public interface Shape {
  int getArea();
}
```

And, you create two new classes:

```
public class MyRectangle extends Rectangle implements Shape {

}

public class MyCircle extends Rectangle implements Shape {

}
```

Since these classes inherit the members of their parent classes, and those already provide an implementation for getArea(), that is all you need to do.

then, change your printArea method to:

```
public void printArea(Shape myShape) {
  System.out.println(myShape.getArea());
}
```

In order for this to work, you'll need to either use instantiate your new classes instead of the old ones, or you need to add a mapper, this can be something like:

```
public static Shape createMyShapes(Object o) throws TechnicalException {
  if ( !(o instanceof Circle || o instanceof Rectangle) )
    throw new TechnicalException("Wrong type"); 
  if ( o instanceof Circle ) 
    return new MyCircle(o);
  return new MyRectangle(o);
}
```

and use that where necessary.

Comment: Bro I can't add interface :(

Comment: @HasanKaanTURAN Bro, in classes you create yourself, yes, you can. Unless you can give a specific reason. Are interfaces outlawed in your company?

Comment: Are interfaces outlawed in your company? of course not :).I will try this.Thank you

Comment: Bro.I have different methods too.What is your advice about this?How can I use

Comment: what do you mean, different methods? methods that are there in one class, but not in the other?

Comment: For example Circle's specific method -> Method1(), and Rectangle dont have Method1() function